# Placing a removable discontinuity in the graph of a function using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to graph the function $y = \sqrt{x^{2} - 4}/\sqrt{x - 2}$ on the domain from -5 to 30. This function will be Sy = \sqrt{x + 2}$ restricted to the open interval $(2, \infty)$.  So, I would like an open circle at (2,0), a dashed line drawn down to the x-axis, and a tick mark there and below it the label "2."  I would also like a tick mark below the x-intercept and below it the label "-2."

Why is solid curve blue and the dashed curve red?  Why is the label of the curve interfering with the curve? What is the "+" in the command "\addplot+"?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=both,
          xmax=41,ymax=6,
          axis lines=middle,
          restrict y to domain=-1.5:6.5,
          enlargelimits,
          axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm,latex-latex},
          ticklabel style={fill=white}]
\addplot+[domain=2:36,mark=none,samples=200] {sqrt(x + 2)} node[fill=white, below]{$y=\frac{x^{2} - 4}{\sqrt{x-2}}$};
\addplot+[domain=-2:2,dashed,mark=none,samples=200] {sqrt(x + 2)};
\draw[fill] (axis cs:2,2) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[below] {$(2,2)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The "+" is the cause of the lines being blue and red. It's the trigger for tikz to cycle through the color list.

Comment: @user143462: You tend to pack a whole bunch of questions into a single post. That is more convenient for you, but it greatly reduces the potential for this post to be useful to other people, because it makes it much harder to Google for the issues covered in your post. Could you please edit your post to cover only a single issue, making sure that your example code is reduced to the minimum necessary for reproducing the problem (no need for `tkz-euclide` here, for example).